# What is PromptOptions.Validations

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

In BotFramework V4 you can validate user inputs using your own validator function:

```
dialogs.Add(new TextPrompt("textPrompt", TextPromptValidatorAsync));
```

But there is also a [Validations Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.promptoptions.validations?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) in PromptOptions class.

```
return await step.PromptAsync(
    TextPrompt,
    new PromptOptions
    {
        Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("What is your name?"),
        Validations = ??
    },
    cancellationToken);
```

What is it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validations are objects that can be used to validate the responses from users.

The sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/9da01cb851335e5cb6542e9905c0d0015a6a9d28/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/10.prompt-validations/PromptValidationsBot.cs) shows an example. Essentially in this sample, it is using an async Task:

```
public Task<bool> CustomPromptValidatorAsync(PromptValidatorContext<string> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

This has the logic to actually check what is valid. Then this is passed in when adding the TextPrompt dialog:

```
    _dialogs.Add(new TextPrompt("name", CustomPromptValidatorAsync));
```

The Validations property is how you can access that object.

Comment: So I can use Validations to pass some info, then deserialize it.
Can I pass, for example, ITurnContext to make it posiible to send messages about validation process?

Comment: You can already get the turn context from PomptValidatorContext. Please refer [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/9da01cb851335e5cb6542e9905c0d0015a6a9d28/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/10.prompt-validations/PromptValidationsBot.cs#L115)